# Is it possible to distinguish randomized devices (iOS) by two Wi-Fi scanners

Tags: wireless-networking, mac, random

I know that iOS uses a randomized media access control (MAC) address when conducting Wi-Fi scans.

In these contexts, when I set-up two scanners in a certain location, can I distinguish the devices which emit randomized MAC?

Using the patterns that scanner A and B may get randomized MAC at the same time, it makes sense I thought.

Could you give some advice or documents related to this work?

Comment: What does distinguish look like? I’m assuming you want to intentionally strip away the privacy Apple designed by randomizing the hardware addresses and track specific devices, but I don’t want to assume if you have a different Y in mind for this XY problem. Also, tracking could mean a couple things: trilateralization or uniquely identifying devices, etc...

Comment: I would like to identify the devices which emits the randomized MAC ID.